# How does Apache Zeppelin visualize data from Hbase?

Tags: database, user-interface, hadoop, hbase, apache-zeppelin

Since Apache Zeppelin supports Hbase as an interpreter and can visualize any backend language that's recognized, I wonder if I can use Zeppelin to directly visualize the data from Hbase?

Right now I can only view the [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzuSV.png) in the Hbase from the zeppelin.

Any suggestions for good alternatives are also welcome. The ultimate goal is to visualize and perform data analytics on a large set of geospatial data.

Comment: You could use Apache Phoenix with the JDBC interpreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can visualize any backend language that's recognized

That's not quite true. The tables and chart visualizations generally require a table structure.

The Hbase interpreter is just [a proxy into the `hbase shell` command on that machine](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/Hbase.html) that Zeppelin runs on, and doesn't reformat the results into a table for Zeppelin to recognize and format as a graph.

If you want to actually visualize something, I believe the general solution is to install Apache Phoenix and use that [as a JDBC interpreter](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/jdbc.html) or install Kylin on Hbase and use that interpreter

[See Phoenix example here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/67178/nifi-for-clickstream-log-ingestion-into-hbase-phoe.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! Since we have to perform some data analytics with Spark, is it possible to visualize from the spark interpreter?

Comment: Yes, DataFrames can be loaded into tables & charts